# wordpress reading static page display posts orderd by date desc

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello i'm kinda new to wordpress and i struggle making a static page displaying posts order by date desc. They are displayed after title and i don't manage to make it work as it should. Here is my page code:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Full Width
*/ 
?>
<?php 
global $wp_query;
$id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
$sidebar = get_post_meta($id, "qode_show-sidebar", true);  

$enable_page_comments = false;
if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_enable-page-comments", true) == 'yes') {
    $enable_page_comments = true;
}

if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_background_color", true) != ""){
    $background_color = get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_background_color", true);
}else{
    $background_color = "";
}

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
        <?php if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_scroll_amount_for_sticky", true)) { ?>
            <script>
            var page_scroll_amount_for_sticky = <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_scroll_amount_for_sticky", true); ?>;
            </script>
        <?php } ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'title' ); ?>
        <?php
        $revslider = get_post_meta($id, "qode_revolution-slider", true);
        if (!empty($revslider)){ ?>
            <div class="q_slider"><div class="q_slider_inner">
            <?php echo do_shortcode($revslider); ?>
            </div></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    <div class="full_width"<?php if($background_color != "") { echo " style='background-color:". $background_color ."'";} ?>>
    <div class="full_width_inner">
        <?php if(($sidebar == "default")||($sidebar == "")) : ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : 
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php 
 $args_pages = array(
  'before'           => '<p class="single_links_pages">',
  'after'            => '</p>',
  'pagelink'         => '<span>%</span>'
 );

 wp_link_pages($args_pages); ?>
                    <?php
                    if($enable_page_comments){
                    ?>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="container_inner">
                    <?php
                        comments_template('', true); 
                    ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?> 
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php elseif($sidebar == "1" || $sidebar == "2"): ?>        

            <?php if($sidebar == "1") : ?>  
                <div class="two_columns_66_33 clearfix grid2">
                    <div class="column1">
            <?php elseif($sidebar == "2") : ?>  
                <div class="two_columns_75_25 clearfix grid2">
                    <div class="column1">
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : 
                        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="column_inner">

                        <?php the_content(); ?> 
                        <?php 
 $args_pages = array(
  'before'           => '<p class="single_links_pages">',
  'after'            => '</p>',
  'pagelink'         => '<span>%</span>'
 );

 wp_link_pages($args_pages); ?>
                            <?php
                            if($enable_page_comments){
                            ?>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="container_inner">
                            <?php
                                comments_template('', true); 
                            ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?> 
                        </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>


                    </div>
                    <div class="column2"><?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                </div>
            <?php elseif($sidebar == "3" || $sidebar == "4"): ?>
                <?php if($sidebar == "3") : ?>  
                    <div class="two_columns_33_66 clearfix grid2">
                        <div class="column1"><?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                        <div class="column2">
                <?php elseif($sidebar == "4") : ?>  
                    <div class="two_columns_25_75 clearfix grid2">
                        <div class="column1"><?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                        <div class="column2">
                <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : 
                            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="column_inner">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>     
                            <?php 
 $args_pages = array(
  'before'           => '<p class="single_links_pages">',
  'after'            => '</p>',
  'pagelink'         => '<span>%</span>'
 );

 wp_link_pages($args_pages); ?>
                            <?php
                            if($enable_page_comments){
                            ?>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="container_inner">
                            <?php
                                comments_template('', true); 
                            ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?> 
                            </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                        </div>

                    </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop like this::

```
   $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
    );
    $query1 = new WP_Query( $args );


    <?php if ($query1->have_posts()) : 
                            while ($query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="column_inner">

                            <?php the_content(); ?> 
                            <?php 
     $args_pages = array(
      'before'           => '<p class="single_links_pages">',
      'after'            => '</p>',
      'pagelink'         => '<span>%</span>'
     );

     wp_link_pages($args_pages); ?>
                                <?php
                                if($enable_page_comments){
                                ?>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="container_inner">
                                <?php
                                    comments_template('', true); 
                                ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?> 
                            </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```